Keyboard on Axioo Mybook Hype 5 is not working in ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
anyone can help me? I still can't find the answer to my problem.
My laptop is Axioo Mybook Hype 5 which launched in 2024. The keyboard is not working at all in Ubuntu, however it still working in Bios and Windows. The problem started from trying/installing Ubuntu using USB bootable media. I had a trouble during installation because both the built-in keyboard and screen keyboard are not working in the step when I asked to create username and password. But the installation process was still successful because an external USB keyboard worked.
I searched the solution in the Ubuntu forum, asked chatGPT and try several suggested solution to make my built-in keyboard works. Until now it still doesn't works.
Is this problem related to hardware compatibility? if it so, what should I do?
the result of xinput list is shown below
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

the result of xinput --list-props 5 and xinput --list-props 9 respectively
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
Device 'Virtual core XTEST keyboard':
    Device Enabled (122):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (124): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    XTEST Device (233): 1

xinput --list-props 9
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
Device 'xwayland-keyboard:15':
    Device Enabled (122):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (124): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000

the result of setxkbmap -query
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an Xwayland server
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us

and the result of sudo hwinfo --keyboard are
18: USB 00.0: 10800 Keyboard                                    
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: Q0Le.5noQb+BnXZ9
  Parent ID: KRJj.d7FDLX76qXB
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1.4/3-1.4:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 3-1.4:1.0
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "CASUE USB KB"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x2a7a 
  Device: usb 0x938f "CASUE USB KB"
  Revision: "0.01"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/event8
  Device Files: /dev/input/event8, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.4-usb-0:1.4:1.0-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.4-usbv2-0:1.4:1.0-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-id/usb-2a7a_CASUE_USB_KB-event-kbd
  Device Number: char 13:72
  Speed: 1.5 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v2A7Ap938Fd0001dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #19 (Hub)

28: PS/2 00.0: 10800 Keyboard
  [Created at input.226]
  Unique ID: c3zD.+49ps10DtUF
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Vendor: 0x0001 
  Device: 0x0001 "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Compatible to: int 0x0211 0x0001
  Device File: /dev/input/event4
  Device Files: /dev/input/event4, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
  Device Number: char 13:68
  Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

What I have done

Manually choose keyboard configuration: I have run the command sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration then I chose Generic 104-key PC, 101 and 102 model. After that I run sudo service keyboard-setup restart but it still doesn't works

Manually load i8042 driver by using sudo modprobe i8042. It still dosesn't work

Edit boot parameter using sudo nano /etc/default/grub find the line


GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
and edit like this
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
save the file (Ctrl+O to write the file, and Ctrl+X to exit)
then sudo update-grub and sudo reboot.
The interesting part is the keyboard is working! But I had several issue such as mouse pad is not detected, the laptop is significantly slower, and the screen brightness just too high. After I now the problem may be in ACPI, I try to fine tune by using acpi=noirq, acpi=ht, acpi_osi=Linux, acpi=strict and pci=noacpi(this command made me stuck while booting). I try those command but my keyboard still not working properly...
Hardware Information
The keyboard is have several special function key "fn" (for function like volume up and down, screen brightness, etc). It's ribbon cable has 26 pin, and it's should be interact to an embedded controller chip iTE IT5570E-128.

have you tried a bootable USB with 24.04.1 in your device? What was the result? Did the keyboard work there? [edit] your question accordingly. "Nothing works" doesn't work for the community... we can't see your device so you will have to explain more for your question to useful. Don't add to the comment trail - [edit] your question

thank you for your response! I update my post. I hope that is enough to answers your questions and suggestion
